# 3D touch in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, 3dtouch

Could somebody share his/her best practice to handle different shortcutItems by parsing launchOptions

```
[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey].
```

When you run the app by one of the Items - how to detect which exactly was tapped?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use and get `UIApplicationShortcutItem` object.

```
UIApplicationShortcutItem *shortcutItem = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey];
NSDictionary *itemInfo = shortcutItem.userInfo;
```

Once you have that you can check using `shortcutItem.userInfo` , it contains dictionary of info you provided while creating `UIApplicationShortcutItem`